# Connect signals and slots of different classes in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

In Qt, my `MainController` class creates a `ViewController` and a `NetworkController` in it's constructor.

After creation I need to connect the `QPushButton::clicked` signal to the `onStartListening` slot in the `NetworkController` class.

**Connection code:**

```
connect(m_viewController->getStartWindow()->getStartListeningButton(),
&QPushButton::clicked, m_networkController, &NetworkController::onStartListening);
```

When I try to compile my code, I get the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x66D641BA (Qt5Cored.dll) in bla.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDD1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to check 1) `m_viewController != nullptr`, 2) `m_viewController->getStartWindow() != nullptr`. There are everything clear from your error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One technique is to get the object inside of connect() and connect the signal of the object to the slot. In your case you are getting the button of start window of viewController.

Another technique is to create a signal in the class and connect this signal to the slot in the parent class. It required a bit more code, but then you don't need to care if object is created or not, because if object is Null then no signal will be emitted.